# Setting a cookie in jquery based on input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I ma really new to javascript but I am using jquery and the jquery cookie library. I was wondering how I can put the contents of an input text box into a cookie.

This is the code I have tried but it hasn't worked:

JS

```
$.cookie("location_input", "#lat");
```

HTML

```
<input id="loc" placeholder="Location" type="text"></input>
```

Is there something else stopping this from working or have I not done this bit of code correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like:

```
$.cookie("location_input", $("#lat").val());
```

At the moment you are setting the cookie to the string value `#lat`, not actual value of the input.

Also I think your example has a typo, `#lat` instead of `#loc` :)

Answer (score 4):

Your HTML is this:

```
<input id="loc" placeholder="Location" type="text"></input>
```

In order to get the contents of an input text box, you should simply do this:

```
var data = $("#loc").val();
```

and to set this **data** into a cookie, you need to do this:

```
$.cookie("location_input", data);
```

I hope, this makes things clear as *why your code didn't worked* :)

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
document.cookie = "location_input="+$("#loc").val();
```

Using `#loc`, since it is the id of your input. `$.cookie` is useful when retrieving the cookie, not nessecary when saving.

Comment: But if you're going to use it to retrieve the cookie value, might as well use it to set it too? ;)

Comment: Maybe I am lazy, or victim of old habits. I use $.cookie too, but when I save cookies, I'm using document.cookie. Uses $.cookie more as a "getter".

Comment: Fair enough, I like to keep both at the same level of abstraction for others in the future. I think it would be confusing to see the cookie set in one way and read in another. Good suggestion though, it's worth pointing out :)